# String Format Specifier in C# for with fixed length of strings in Gridview

Tags: c#, string, format-specifiers

I am trying to display string with fixed length (say 10 Digits of strings) in Grid view item template while binding, i could not find any Format specifiers for the string itself.

i can get format specifiers for (`Numbers{0:N}`, `Floats & Decimal (D)`, `Currency{0:C}`, , `Date{1,8:yyyy}` , `Percentage {0,3:P1}`,`Temperature: {0:F}`, `Exponential`, `Hexadecimal` ... **But Not For String Itself**)

I tried links:   [Click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/26etazsy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  but didn't work for me.

My Grid view have an Template Field (Item Template)

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Notes">
     <ItemTemplate>

     <asp:Label ID="Label_Note" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Format("{0}", Eval("Defect_Note").ToString()) %>'  ></asp:Label>   

    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

I need to display '**Notes Column**' in below grid with max 10 digits. if exeeds it should not show (can show on tooltip) if less than 10 it can show all its content.

[image]

**I wanted to display the Notes columns like  `Printf(" %8s" ,&note)` in C#.** (in Binding single line)

Comment: probably spaces are getting trimmed.

Comment: If you want to display the first 10 characters than you need to trim it or take first 10 chars, string.format will not truncate it for you.

Comment: You say you need the string to be of fixed length: If the string is four characters does it need to be padded to 10 characters? From the context you are using it I assume not but wanted to clarify.

Comment: You could add a `Defect_Note_Display` property to your view model: `public string Defect_Note_Display { get { return Defect_Note.Substring(0,10); } }` or similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to check for null values.

```
notes.Substring(0, Math.Min(notes.Length, 10))
```

Answer (score 1):

below code help with you

```
<asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server"
                Text='<%# Limit(Eval("Description"),10) %>' 
                Tooltip='<%# Eval("Description") %>'>
      </asp:Label>
```

Refer this link:

[How to limit label string length in GridView with Read More link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012942/how-to-limit-label-string-length-in-gridview-with-read-more-link)

Comment: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Limit' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Rahul: I assume Limit is a custom method that Senthilkumar forgot to include in his answer. I suspect it will have similar content to hazimdikenli's answer though.